# BooFuzz Define a character set when fuzzing

Tags: fuzzing

Say I wanted to only fuzz with alphanumeric characters or specific strings with boofuzz. Is there a way to force this behavior? In sulley you can make a file named .fuzz_strings that I think does something like, is there something similar to this in boofuzz?

Comment: What feature in Sulley allows this? Most any feature in Sulley should also be available in boofuzz.

Comment: From the Sulley manual: "Sulley's primitives contain an internal "fuzz library", a list of potentially interesting values to cycle through. If you
don't want to hack source file to extend the fuzz library for strings and/or integers you can do so externally with
ease. Simply create a .fuzz_strings or .fuzz_ints file in the directory you are launching your fuzz driver from. Put
each fuzz value on it's own line. Sulley will update the primitive libraries at run-time with values from these files." I tried it and it seemed to work.

Comment: Nice. Did it work with Sulley but not boofuzz? If so I'd consider that a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to fuzz from a specific list of characters or strings. To make it yourself, you could extend `BasePrimitive`. See `boofuzz/primitives/string.py` for an example.

You can also open an issue and make a feature request on the Github repository: https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz/issues

Comment: Thanks I'll look at the BasePrimitive.